# After trying alot of comand I am getting the same ERROR (nodemon: not found command)

Tags: node.js

> nodemon: not found command

I tried with many links to solve nodemon not found command but it is not working.

Always facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

nodemon: not found command.
I tried with many links but was not working, then I tried with the below steps it worked fine.

Follow this step it worked for me.

step1 : sudo su

step2 : npm install -g nodemon --save-dev

It is working fine.